# Why can't my machine connect to the Internet?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet, lan, internet-connection

I have a self-built desktop running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It is connected by an Ethernet cable (not wireless!) to a Apple Time Capsule (identical to an Airport Extreme). The Time Capsule has an illuminated LED on that port indicating that it is connected to the machine. However, the computer cannot access either the network or the Internet, and my other computers don't see it on the network. What could be causing this?

ifconfig displays:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
      RX Packets:308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frames:0
      TX Packets:308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueueline:0
      RX bytes:23600 (23.6 KB) TX bytes:23600 (23.6 KB)
```

Comment: Does it have an IP address? Can you ping said IP address? How did you configure the network settings? Just looking for some background info.

Comment: type ifconfig into teminal. that should display the network connections and settings.

Comment: it would be interesting to know what you get when you type:

"dmesg | grep eth0"


apparently your Ethernet card isn't configured or isn't recognized.

Comment: @gbroiles Nothing comes up. Motherboards typically do come with Ethernet cards, right?

Comment: usually, yes - but it's possible that either the Ethernet port is disabled in the BIOS, or else Ubuntu doesn't have a driver for it.

Comment: @gbro A bit late, but I finally got around to messing with the BIOS, and it fixed it. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It only displays your localhost. So either Ubuntu has no driver for your card or the networking daemon isn´t running. 
Try this command 
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`
It should restart the daemon. 
You can use this command with the params `start|stop|restart|force-reload`